# Unabe to Start Jenkins on Gradle installed Server

Tags: jenkins, gradle

I installed Gradle with following versions and was working perfectly fine,
 Gradle server has Java version,

- openjdk version "1.8.0_342"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_342-b07)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.342-b07, mixed mode)

and gradle version:

- Gradle 6.8.3

I would be able to run "./gradlew build" to build our github repository successfully.
 
But,
 When I tried Installing Jenkins on the same server,I'm not able start jenkins i,e. systemctl start jenkins
this is throwing below error:

- "Job for jenkins.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status jenkins.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

I wonder, this would be because Java version , because jenkins requires "Java-jdk11".
 
I tried to installed java-jdk11, jenkins was running up and fine , but not able to run gradle command  - "./gradlew build" (we can run this command if java version is -openjdk version "1.8.0_342").
 
is there any way to come out this?

Thanks for your Help!